# aws-sdk for ruby. How to assign a public ip address with instance?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

After thoroughly reading the [ruby aws-sdk docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/frames.html), I dont see a way to associate a public ip address with an instance when creating inside a VPC. I dont want to manage elastic IP addresses, just have the good old random public ip.

```
instance = ec2.instances.create(
  count: 1,
  image_id: IMAGE_ID,
  instance_type: INSTANCE_TYPE,
  key_name: KEYNAME,
  subnet_id: SUBNET_ID,
  security_groups: security_group,
  user_data: USER_DATA
)
```

Anyone know the simplest way to associate a public address on ec2 instance creation?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/EC2/Client/V20131015.html#run_instances-instance_method, Under `run_instances` method, Under `:network_interfaces` option, you can use `:associate_public_ip_address` input parameter to specify assignment of the Public IP address.

FYI, You are using older version of Ruby SDK. Use [AWS SDK CORE](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/frames.htm) as AWS is focusing more on Core SDK now a days. Above option for assigning Public ip address in AWS SDK CORE can be found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/EC2/V20131015.html#run_instances-instance_method).

Answer (score 1):

Here is some sample code to launch an instance in a VPC with a public IP address, using version 2.2 of the Ruby AWS SDK. As far as I can tell, this is the minimum amount of code needed in order to launch an instance that actually has a public IP address. All the variables named `my-something` would need to be set first, of course.

```
require 'aws-sdk'
@ec2 = Aws::EC2::Resource.new
@ec2.create_instances(dry_run: false,
                      min_count: 1,
                      max_count: 1,
                      image_id: my-image-id,
                      key_name: my-key-name,
                      network_interfaces: [{device_index: 0,
                                            subnet_id: my-subnet-id,
                                            groups: [my-security-group-id],
                                            delete_on_termination: true,
                                            associate_public_ip_address: true}]
```